# Can we still use the variable delegate for variable pass through parameter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

We have the below compose which works well.

```
@Composable
fun MyInnerControl() {
    var timerStartStop by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    Button(onClick = {
        timerStartStop = !timerStartStop
    }) {
        Text(if (timerStartStop) "Stop" else "Start")
    }
}
```

But if we have the `timerStartStop` passed through the function parameter, I cannot do as below

```
@Composable
fun MyInnerControl(timerStartStop: Boolean) {
    Button(onClick = {
        timerStartStop = !timerStartStop
    }) {
        Text(if (timerStartStop) "Stop" else "Start")
    }
}
```

I can pass as below, but then I have to change my `timerStartStop` to `timerStartStop.value`

```
@Composable
fun MyInnerControl(timerStartStop: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    Button(onClick = {
        timerStartStop.value = !timerStartStop.value
    }) {
        Text(if (timerStartStop.value) "Stop" else "Start")
    }
}
```

Is there any way to have the `MutableState<Boolean>` passed over the argument, yet within the function we can use the delegate approach, i.e. using `timerStartStop` instead of `timerStartStop.value`?

Comment: What's being tried above is an anti-pattern, and should be avoided. It's great that the By Variable Delegate helped expose it. https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/how-kotlin-by-variable-delegate-helps-me-avoid-anti-pattern-558004000341?sk=2f28b25141c2eb38b6991d29b92e901d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetpack Compose tells you to respect **Single Source of Truth** principle, which means that you can not pass state as argument if you want to change that state inside your function.

So generally you have to choose one of two approaches:

1. Pass both timerStartStop variable and onClick callback

```
@Composable
fun MyInnerControl(timerStartStop: Boolean, onClick: ()->Unit) {
    Button(onClick = onClick) {
        Text(if (timerStartStop) "Stop" else "Start")
    }
}
```

2. Pass none of these

```
@Composable
fun MyInnerControl() {
    var timerStartStop by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    Button(onClick = {
        timerStartStop = !timerStartStop
    }) {
        Text(if (timerStartStop) "Stop" else "Start")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to apply proper state hoisting methods and give `MyInnerControl` the ability to both read and edit the parameter in the following way.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ParentComposable() {
  val isTimerRunning by remember { mutableStateOf(false) } }
  MyInnerControl(
    isTimerRunning = isTimerRunning,
    flipTimerState {
      isTimerRunning = !isTimerRunning
    }
  }
}

@Composable
fun MyInnerControl(
  isTimerRunning: Boolean,
  flipTimerState: () -> Unit,
) {
  Button(
    onClick = { flipTimerState() }
  ) {
    Text(if (isTimerRunning) "Stop" else "Start")
  }
}
```